# Flutterweb deployment issue on vercel

Tags: flutter, vercel

I'm encountering difficulties deploying my Flutter web application on Vercel. While everything works smoothly in development, I face numerous errors upon pushing the code for deployment.

Any insights or tips from those experienced with deploying Flutter web apps on Vercel would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[Vercel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKQpd.png)

I have deployed several flutter web on vercel and never gotten this issue

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to fix this issue few minutes after posting it. All i had to do was switch to stable channel.

1. flutter channel beta
2. Flutter clean, get packages and push again

it will redownload flutter and other important things